# Are these two logical comparisons equivalent?

Tags: bash, case

Given the variable:

```
path="a/b/c"
```

Are these two logical comparisons equivalent?

```
[[ $path = */* ]] && echo 1
```

and

```
case $path in
   */*)
      echo 1
   ;;
esac
```

Is each case effectively equivalent to a bracket test construct? And is there any disparity for `case` against `[` vs `[[`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the pattern `*/*`, `case` and `[[` will behave identically.

However, `[[` always accepts extended globs (so it ignores the setting of shell option `extglob`), while `case` only allows extended globs if `extglob` is set. So if the pattern had been an extended glob and `extglob` were not set, the two constructs would act differently. (Most likely, the use of an extended glob in a `case` pattern would result in a syntax error.)

`[` does not do pattern matching. The arguments to the command `[ $path = */* ]` will undergo filename expansion before the command is interpreted, which is likely to result in bash complaining that `[` has too many arguments (unless you have some interestingly named files or there is only exactly one file which matches `*/*`).

Comment: `bash` 4.1 is the first version in which `[[` treats all patterns as extended patterns by default, although in late 2017 it is probably safe to assume that, macOS users aside, very few people are using an older version. (Incidentally, 4.1 also has a compile-time option to enable `extglob` by default.)